# Anyone has a better way of efficiently creating a DataFrame from 60000 txt Files with keys in one column and values in the second?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dna-sequence, dask-dataframe

**Disclaimer !!** This is my first post ever, so sorry if I don't meet certain standards of the community.
  _________________  _________________  _________________  _________________  _________________


I use python3, Jupyter Notebooks, Pandas

I used KMC kmer counter to count kmers of 60,000 DNA sequences in a reasonable amount of time. I want to use these kmer counts as input to ML algorithms as part of a Bag Of Words model.

The shape of a file containing kmer counts is as below, or as in [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hYxO.jpg)  and I have 60K files:

AAAAAC       2 
AAAAAG       6 
AAAAAT      2 
AAAACC       4 
AAAACG       2 
AAAACT       3 
AAAAGA       5

I want to create a single DataFrame from all the 60K files with one line per DNA sequence kmer counts which would have this form:
[The target DataFrame shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z1nS.jpg)

A first approach was successful and I managed to import 100 sequences(100 txt files) in 58 seconds, using this code:

```
import time

countsPath = r'D:\DataSet\MULTI\bow\6mer'
start = time.time()

for i in range(0, 60000):
    sample = pd.read_fwf(countsPath + r'\kmers-' + str(k) +'-seqNb-'+ str(i) + '.txt',sep=" ", header=None).T
    new_header = sample.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
    sample = sample[1:] #take the data less the header row
    sample.columns = new_header #set the header row as the df header
    
    df= df.append(sample, ignore_index=True)  #APPEND Sample to df DataSet

    
end = time.time()
# total time taken
print(f"Runtime of the program is {end - start} secs")


#     display(sample)
display(df)
```

However, this was very slow,  and took 59 secs on 100 files. On the full dataset, take a factor of x600. 
I tried **dask** **DataFrames Bag** to accelerate the process because it reads dictionary-like data, but I couldn't append each file as a row. The resulting Dask DataFrame is as follows [or as in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxuqb.jpg):

0          AAAAA   18 
1          AAAAC   16
2          AAAAG   13

...
1023   TTTTT   14
0          AAAAA   5
1          AAAAC   4
...
1023   TTTTT   9
0          AAAAA   18 
1          AAAAC   16
2          AAAAG   13
3          AAAAT   12
4          AAACA   11

So the files are being inserted in a single column.

**Anyone has a better way of efficiently creating a DataFrame from 60k txt Files?**

Answer (score 0):

Love the disclaimer.  I have a similar one - this is the first time I'm trying to answer a question.  But I'm pretty certain I got this...and so will you:

dict_name = dict(zip(df['column_name'],df['the_other_column_name']))

Comment: The problem involves constructing a very large dataframe by reading tens of thousands of files. Your answer seems to be how to create a dictionary from that dataframe once it has been constructed. Your answer thus assumes that the core problem has already been solved.

Comment: @JohnColeman is totally right. I need to create a DataFrame of the whole DataSet from 60k files of dict-like format (two columns) with single header (kmer names) and the counts for each file per line (preserving order, so file 0 -> line 0 etc.) because I am using supervised learning.

Comment: Oops...completely missed that part.  I blame being a code zombie last night.